# Generating spring xml files runtime

Tags: java, xml, spring, runtime, javabeans

I wrote an application which uses spring framework. now i wanted to write a code which consumes some inputs from somewhere and then produce some spring configuration xml file. the problem is that, can i give these files to spring when my application is running and my applications is passed over "XMLApplicationContext" creation object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are talking about having multiple `ApplicaitonContext` base on user input right? This is doable. Take a look at `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` in Spring framework. You can generate the XML, and pass the xml to `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` to create new application context.